# List of adb devices in command prompt not showing

Tags: android, adb

I've been trying to run adb on my laptop. At first, it just wouldn't run at all. Now, after trying different fixes, I've gotten the daemon to start, but it won't list my phone as an attached device. I don't know if it's a driver issue or a cable issue or something else. I'm honestly pretty stumped.

Comment: Are you running as `root`?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 No.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'm pretty sure that adb requires root privileges in order to detect devices. Try running the daemon as root using `sudo`.